# Getting back to playing piano after 15 years of little practice

Tags: piano, digital-piano

I have just recently bought a digital piano after years of not being able to play.  15 years ago, my level was intermediate. I could play classical and jazz songs which were quite hard. Now I feel like I've forgotten how to read solfege but eager to get back into it. 
What is the best way for me to get back into it? Type of exercises? I can still play two songs by memory.. but I definitely want to get ahead and play more (mostly blues/jazz)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a jazz piano teacher in London and have many students who have mainly played classical music in the past. I work from 'Real books' which just contain the tune and chords. Brush up on your reading and get used to the flat keys (particularly F, Bb and Eb). Then re-aquaint yourself with the chord symbols.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't realise classical and jazz tunes were written in solfege. If you play(ed) from the dots , then get some easy tunes and let yourself in gently. If you play(ed) by ear, listen to some of the easier jazz tunes and play along with them, splitting play between left and right hands. Get used to the sets of notes that are used in jazz/blues - blues scale, modes etc. in as many keys as possible, so you will be able to play in any key eventually. I know you can probably change the tuning on your digital piano, but it can get very samey if you only play in one key (with one set of notes). Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Start slow, gently with lots of feelings that your hands and feelings can muster; then limber up as you repeat; and finally go for the real performance with a gusto once your limbs and body are tuned to it!